# swift выдает ошибку Use of unresolved identifier 'countLable' хотя сountLable объявлен и привязан

Tags: swift

вот в коде объявлен countLable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var countLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var botomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

а в extention он на него так ругается вот так Use of unresolved identifier 'countLable', не пойму что он от меня хочет

```
extension UIViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

public func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { // срабратывает при тапе
    textView.backgroundColor = .white
    textView.textColor = .gray
}
public func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { // срабаотывает по окогчанию
    textView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
    textView.textColor = .black
    
}
public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    countLable.text = "\(textView.text.count)"
    return textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 60
}
```

}

Вот тот же код но в старом xcode и при этом все работает

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate { 
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.backgroundColor = .white 
            textView.textColor = .gray 
    } func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor 
            textView.textColor = .black 
    } func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: 
      NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool { 
             countLable.text = "\(textView.text.count)" return 
    textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 60 
       } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас написан extension к UIViewController, а нужно написать extension к конкретному контроллеру, чтобы "видеть" его свойства:

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {...}
```

Extension (расширение) применяется к конкретной сущности, т.е. если вы пишете extension UIViewController {...}, то вы расширяете именно UIViewController - дополняете его новыми методами. В вашем случае вы хотите добавить методы к другому контроллеру, который называется ViewController, поэтому вам нужно писать extension ViewController {...}

Comment: не очень понял если честно, могли бы по подробнее. За ответ спасибо.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое все получилось. Только вот такой еще вопрос у меня на виртуалке стоит 11 xcode и там первый вариант, кода который я скинул отлично работает без дополнительного extansion почему так ?

Comment: Это не зависит от Xcode. Есть понятие области видимости. UIViewController не "видит" свойство countLable, потому что оно определено в другом контроллере, ViewController. Значит, код не совсем такой. Сравните еще раз.

Comment: в том то и дело что сравнивал, у меня создалось впечатления что есть разница в каком xcode, приложение ниже код, объясните если не сложно

Comment: Обратите внимание, что там, где и так работает, написано "extension ViewController", а там, где нет - "extension UIViewController", в этом разница и это разные классы.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо большое